# facing issue, while creating List with in re.compile python regex

Tags: python

I am trying to create a List with regex in a Python shell.
In list I have 3 value topic-1, topic-2, topic-3. I am creating one consumer object which is having topic and topic should contains 3 values [topic1, topic2, topic3]. so Whenever I want to point any one from topic-1, topic-2, topic-3. so it should take a message from right topic.
I am following below code but it's giving one issue:

```
import pulsar
import re

client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://localhost:6650')
topic = 'my-topic'
topic = ['topic-1', 'topic-2', 'topic-3']
topic = re.compile('topic-.*')
print(topic)
# <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f13314e7210> 
consumer = client.subscribe(topic, "my-subscription")
2019-04-26 07:05:02.956 INFO  ConnectionPool:72 | Created connection for 
pulsar://localhost:6650
2019-04-26 07:05:02.957 INFO  ClientConnection:300 | [127.0.0.1:55874 -> 
127.0.0.1:6650] Connected to broker
```

Here I am able to create consumer object, But it's not creating with right value like `[topic-1, topic-2, topic-3]`
because in next step I am not able to receive the message.
What would be the syntax issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything overtly wrong in your syntax. Are you sure you have those topics in your namespace? Try using pulsar's command line tools, e.g.:

pulsar-admin tenants list

pulsar-admin namespaces list <>

pulsar-admin topics list tenant/cluster/namespace

See here for more options: https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/latest/reference/CliTools/

Comment: bin/pulsar-admin persistent list public/default
null

Reason: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: In above code, consumer is not creating because It should return Created consumer on broker [127.0.0.1:37086 -> 127.0.0.1:6650] , But I am not getting any notification for above code.

Comment: Looks like something's broken with your server. Can you get anything out of it, not through pulsar?